# Filebeat is not creating my custom index?

Tags: filebeat

I hope everyone is doing well.
I am using filebeat to ship cisco syslog (with using filebeat cisco module) to elasticsearch. And apparently it is not using my custom index, instead logs go to default index filebeat-*.

Note: the field host.name is a custom field.
-also tried disabling and enabling ILM but no luck.

**Below is my filebeat.yml config:**

```
# ============================== Filebeat inputs ===============================

filebeat.inputs:
- type: filestream
  id: my-filestream-id
  enabled: false
  paths:
    - /var/log/*.log
    #- c:\programdata\elasticsearch\logs\*


- type: syslog
  enabled: false
  paths:
    - /var/log/*.log

# ============================== Filebeat modules ==============================

filebeat.config.modules:
  # Glob pattern for configuration loading
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

  # Set to true to enable config reloading
  reload.enabled: false

# ======================= Elasticsearch template setting =======================
setup.template.overwrite: true
setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1

# =================================== Kibana ===================================

setup.kibana:
  host: "http://172.30.169.50:5000"
  ssl.verification_mode: "none"
  username: "elastic"
  password: "m4gN3s1@.123"
# ---------------------------- Elasticsearch Output ----------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["172.30.169.50:9200"]
  ssl.verification_mode: "none"
  username: "elastic"
  password: "secret"
  indices:
    - index: "sbx-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.contains:
        fields:
          host.name: "SBX"
    - index: "core-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.contains:
        fields:
          host.name: "-CS0"
    - index: "access%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.contains:
        fields:
          host.name: "-AS0"
    - index: "bgp-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.contains:
        fields:
          host.name: "RTRBGP"
    - index: "iplc-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.contains:
        fields:
          host.name: "IPLC0"
    - index: "asp-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.contains:
        fields:
          host.name: "ASP0"
    - index: "sfs-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.contains:
        fields:
          host.name: "SFS0"
    - index: "Local_Loop-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.contains:
        fields:
          host.name: "LL0"
    - index: "mpls-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.contains:
        fields:
           host.name: "MPLS"
    - index: "fortinet-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when.contains:
        fields:
          event.module: "fortinet"
# ================================= Processors =================================
processors:
  - add_host_metadata:
      when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~


  - drop_fields:
      when:
        equals:
          event.module: "cisco"
      fields: ["agent.ephemeral_id","agent.hostname","agent.id","agent.type","agent.version","agent.name","cisco.ios.facility","ecs.version","event.cod>
  - drop_fields:
      when:
        equals:
          event.module: "fortinet"
      fields: ["agent.ephemeral_id","agent.hostname","agent.id","agent.type","agent.version","agent.name","ecs.version","event.code","event.dataset","e>
  - dissect:
      when:
       equals:
          event.module: "cisco"
      tokenizer: "%{address}:%{}"
      field: "log.source.address"
      target_prefix: "host"
  - dissect:
      when:
        equals:
          event.module: "cisco"
      tokenizer: "%{} %{name} %{}"
      field: "log.original"
      target_prefix: "host"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran across your problem while searchig for my own. And i doubt your are still having problems with this, but maybe it helps some others.

I would say your problem is that you don't specify your IndexTemplate as well as your data stream:

```
setup.template.name:<yours_template_name>-%{[agent.version]}
setup.template.pattern:<yours_template_name>-%{[agent.version]}
```